# fixed placeholder in textfield jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]I wanna placeholder to not disappear when user write something

I tried to use this

```
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = input,
                onValueChange = onInputChange,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    autoCorrect = false,
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
                ),
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

            )
            Text(text = placeholder,modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp,bottom = 1.dp))
        }
```

but it doesn't work very well

Comment: What do you mean by "placeholder to not disappear when user writes something". Can you share screenshots of what you are trying to do? Or add more details.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve what is shown in the screenshot?
Can you please add more context on why you need overlapping texts? It reduces the clarity of both texts.

Comment: @Abhimanyu, Hello! I have the same problem, in my question I attached a screenshot of why this is needed. Can you take a look? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813880/always-display-placeholder-and-rtl-input-in-textfield-with-jetpack-compose

Comment: you could try using `leadingIcon` and `trailingIcon` in the `TextField`

Answer (score 0):

This is Compose. Can't you just do:

```
leadingIcon={Text(text="To")}
```