# Always display placeholder and RTL input in TextField with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want the placeholder not to disappear if I start typing in a field and it should be on the left side of the screen.
But the text input and cursor must be on the right.

An example is in the screenshot. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Ok. Got the scenario. This is not the placeholder definition in Android. I will look into this if this can be solved.

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of is to have a Box and a Text with the "to" as a Text overlapping the TextField. Will look if there is any better alternative.

Comment: @Abhimanyu understood your idea, I will try it, thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but it works.

Customizing the `placeholder` as per the requirement is not possible at this point in time. You have to create a completely customized `TextField` if that is an absolute requirement.

**Note**.

1. This is not a placeholder.
2. The positioning of the text is absolute, it should be adjusted according to the `TextField` size.

[image: Screenshot]

```
@Composable
fun FixedPlaceholder() {
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Box {
        OutlinedTextField(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
            value = name,
            onValueChange = {
                name = it
            },
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(
                    horizontal = 16.dp,
                    vertical = 8.dp,
                ),
        )
        Text(
            text = "to",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(
                    start = 32.dp,
                    end = 32.dp,
                    top = 24.dp,
                    bottom = 8.dp
                ),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the placeholder, just set the leadingIcon property to:

```
leadingIcon={Text(text="To")}
```

In Compose, leadingIcon is a composable, and you can set it to anything you like.